# .append() и кнопка loadmore

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При нажатии кнопки на кнопку loadMore, кнопки внутри списка , умножаются с каждым нажатием, как этого избежать ? Возможно нужен другой подход?

это html

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 block1">

      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="button-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="loadMore">
        Load More
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="" id="card_temp">
<div class="card-content select" id="inside">
  <div class="image"><img src="%img%" alt="" /></div>
  <p class="title">%nametitle%</p>
  <div class="types-cont">        
  </div>
  <div id="type">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-type">%type%</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#card_temp{display:none;}

#type{
  display:none;
}
```

jquery

```
 function addType(){
$('.card-content').each(function(i,elem){
 $.get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + (i+1), function(data){
  var type = $('#type').html();
   if(data.types.length>=2){
      for(var i = 1; i <= data.types.length;i++){
              $(elem).append(type);
              var button = $(elem).find('.btn-type').eq(i);
              var typeName = data.types[i-1].type.name;
              $(button).html(capLet(typeName));
              getTypeColor(typeName, button);
            }
    }
       else{
         $(elem).append(type);
         var button = $(elem).find('.btn-type');
         var typeName = data.types[0].type.name;
          $(elem).find('.btn-type').html(data.types[0].type.name);             
          $(button).html(capLet(typeName));
          getTypeColor(typeName,button);
    }
  });
});
};

$('body').on('click','#loadMore',function(){
  $('.block1 ul').append('<li></li> <li></li> <li></li>');

  getImage();
  getPokemon();
  addType();


});
```

По идее должно добавляться только к динамически добавленым li ? но добавляется ко всем классам .card-content. Не знаю как решить проблему.

---

[image: это верхние эелементы после нажатия]

как сделать что бы кнопки добавлялись только к новым?

---

[image: это до нажатия]

Элементы до нажатия. Как сделать что бы так выглядили и новые карточки, а не как на скрине выше

Comment: приведите **минимальный, рабочий пример** здесь в сниппете. либо на jsfiddle

Comment: В функции addtype() var type это кнопка, вы ее и добавляете неоднократно внутри each.